# Minimum deviation of prism

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Is it right to say angle of minimum deviation of a prism is an arithmetic mean of incident angle and emergent angle?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/prism.html#c2

Answer (score 1):

The angle of minimum deviation occurs when the incident angle and exit angle are equal, so no.

Comment: Indeed, the symmetric situation. It must be like that because of reversibility of the light path.